# Folland Exercise 3.8

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\nu$ is a signed measure and $\mu$ is a positive measure then $\nu \ll \mu$ iff ${\nu}^{+} \ll \mu$ and ${\nu}^{-} \ll \mu$.

My try:

Converse part is easy.

For forward implication, let $\nu \ll \mu$ and $E \in \mathcal{M}$ such that $\mu(E)=0$

$\Rightarrow \nu(E)=0$

$\Rightarrow {\nu}^{+}(E)={\nu}^{-}(E)$

Since ${\nu}^{+}\perp {\nu}^{-}$ $\exists P,N \in \mathcal{M}$ such that P is ${\nu}^{-}$ null and N is $\nu^{+}$ null.

$\Rightarrow$ $\nu^+(E)=\nu(E \cap P)$

But I am not able to proceed and show ${\nu}^{+}(E)=0$

Thanks for help!

Comment: If I am not mistaken one has by definition that a complex measure $\nu$ is absolutely continuous wrt $\mu$ iff $\lvert \nu \lvert$ is absolutely continuous wrt $\mu$.

Comment: $\nu$ is a signed measure @TheOscillator

Comment: @Monika, what is your definition of $\nu \ll \mu$ when $\nu$ is a signed measure?  I think that's what TheOscillator is getting at.

Comment: if $\nu$ is signed measure and $\mu$ is a positive measure $\nu$ is absolutely continuous w.r.t $\mu$ and denoted as $\nu << \mu$ if $\nu(E)=0$ for every $E\in \mathcal{M}$ for which $\mu(E)=0$.

Answer (score 5):

Let $X = P \cup N$ be the Hahn decomposition of the measure space, and $\nu = \nu^+ - \nu^-$.

Assume $\nu \ll \mu$. Let's check that $\nu^+(E)=\nu^-(E) = 0$. We know that since $\mu(E) = 0$ and $\mu$ is positive, $P \cap E \subseteq E$ gives $\mu(P \cap E) = 0$ and so $\nu(P \cap E) = 0$. But this is $\nu^+(E)$. Similarly $\nu^-(E) = 0$.

The converse is easy: if $\nu^+ \ll \mu$ and $\nu^- \ll \mu$, then $\mu(E) = 0$ implies $\nu^+(E) = \nu^-(E) = 0$, whence $\nu(E) = \nu^+(E) - \nu^-(E) = 0-0 = 0$, as wanted.

Comment: It would be helpful to indicate which definition of absolute continuity (for signed measures) you are using.

Comment: I take as definition that $\nu \ll \mu$ if  each measurable $E$ with $\mu(E)=0$ also satisfies $\nu(E)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Exercise 8 - If $\nu\ll \mu$ if and only if $|\nu|\ll \mu$ if and only if $\nu^+\ll\mu$ and $\nu^-\ll\mu$.

**Proof:**
Suppose $\nu\ll \mu$. If $E\in M$ and $\mu(E) = 0$ then, for any $F\in M$ such that $F\subseteq E$, we have $\mu(F) = 0$ so we have
$$\nu(F) = 0 $$
So $E$ is $\nu$-null. By exercise 2, $|\nu|(E) = 0$. Therefore, $|\nu|\ll \mu$.

Now suppose $|\nu|\ll \mu$. If $E\in M$ and $\mu(E) = 0$ then $$\nu^+(E) +\nu^-(E)=|\nu|(E) = 0$$ and hence $$\nu^+(E) = \nu^-(E) = 0$$ This shows that $\nu^+\ll \mu$ and $\nu^-\ll \mu$.

Finally, suppose that $\nu^+\ll\mu$ and $\nu^-\ll\mu$. If $E\in M$ and $\mu(E) = 0$, then $$\nu(E) = \nu^+(E) - \nu^-(E) = 0$$ and hence $\nu\ll\mu$